# No valid contact info for 401k sponsor to allow transfer of funds

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, finance

I was employed from 2018-2020 by Company A, during which I contributed funds to their 401k plan.

I was laid off from A in 2020. At some point in time after this, Company A was acquired by Company B. I do not know anyone who still works for A nor B. And no one at B knows me nor who I am.

After exhaustive searching, I still have not found valid contact information for the HR department at Company B. The Plan Administrator (who has my account / funds) informed me of two things:

1. They gave me the only phone number they have on file for the Plan Sponsor, which leads to a generic voicemail that isn't returning calls
2. They also informed me that I must get the signoff by the HR department of B before they will transfer my funds. I don't know how this can be done if I can not obtain their contact info.

I apologize if this isn't strictly a legal question, but what are the next recommended actions to take?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because finding customer service numbers isn't a legal question.

Comment: Customer service is not HR; I'm surprised you would equate the two. The only people that can sign off on me accessing my funds do not provide their contact info. I sure as hell think there's a potential legal issue in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that Company B is an entity rather than an individual, it has a registered agent for service of process which is a matter of public record with the Secretary of State in the state in which it is organized. You can send a demand letter to that address.

If no registered agent can be located, you can send a demand letter to the address of the principal office of the Company.

Either way, you would want to send certified mail so that you can prove that you sent the demand if there is a dispute later on.

Comment: Fantastic advice - thank you. I didn't think of going the registered agent route. Marked this as my solution. They have offices in a couple of states, but I'm happy to hit the various Secretary of State sites and do searches.